# How to vertically center align the bottom of a horizontal list of items of varying heights

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve the following layout without using absolute positioning

[image]

The reason is that I would like to use css grid or flexbox as much as possible and try to avoid taking thins out of the flow if at all possible. In this case the surrounding div has a padding which should be respected, if it comes to that, and instead it should increase it's height if necessary. Usually I use max-content with css grid to achieve this.

If it was only the text it would have been as easy as align-items: center; however, because of the images/badges, the text will not properly align in the center if I do this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-t4h6ff?file=style.css

```css
.list {
  width              : 100%;
  background         : red;
  display            : flex;
  flex-direction     : row;
  align-items        : center;
  }
.list-item {
  background         : yellow;
  display            : grid;
  grid-template-rows : max-content max-content;
  padding            : 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-item">list item 1</div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div>image</div>
    <div>list item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div>image</div>
    <div>list item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4xy14d?file=style.css is what I want to achieve, but without position absolute or transform translate.

Ended up with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-78pckz?file=style.css

```css
html,
body,
#root,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(5rem, 50%) auto;
  background: purple;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}
.list-item {
  background: yellow;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content 1fr;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.text {
  align-self: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
      <div> </div>
      <div class="text">list item 1</div>
      <div> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
      </div>
      <div class="text">list item 2</div>
      <div> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
      </div>
      <div class="text">list item 3</div>
      <div> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>... :-)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `align-items : flex-end;` on `.list`

Comment: That will not solve the problem that list item 1, list item 2 and list item 3 will not be centered. Then it will just be pushed down to the bottom :-)

Comment: With align-items : flex-end; on .list

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-25drxm?file=style.css

Then the main problem still remains. The bottom line (text eg. list item 1, list item2 and list item 3) should be centered within the outer div.

Comment: Basically this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4xy14d?file=style.css , but without the transform translate (or position absolute, or anything else that takes it out of the flow)

Comment: `align-items:end;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's the most elegant solution, but here's how I would solve the problem (assuming your diagram is saying that the size of the images are going to be consistent).

Edit: Didn't *quite* get there with my answers, but it did help Dac0d3r come up with this final solution. Source from him is in the comments.

```css
  
  html,
  body,
  #root,
  .wrapper {
    height             : 100%;
    width              : 100%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    display            : grid;
    grid-template-rows : minmax(5rem, 50%) auto;
    background         : purple;
   }
  .list {
    width              : 100%;
    background         : red;
    display            : flex;
    flex-direction     : row;
    height             : 100%;
  }
  .list-item {
    background         : yellow;
    display            : grid;
    grid-template-rows : 50% 50%;
    padding            : 1rem;
    box-sizing         : border-box;
    height             : 100%;
  }

  .image {
     max-width         : 100%;
     max-height        : 100%;
     align-self        : end;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="list-item">
        <div></div>
        <div class="text">list item 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <div class="text">list item 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <div class="text">list item 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's essential that the list item 1, list item 2, list item 3 is centered within the surrounding div.

Comment: @Dac0d3r I added `justify-content: center` inside the `.list` style in my post. Is that the results your looking for? Sorry if I'm not understanding properly, I don't often "speak design".

Comment: I meant vertically aligned, not horizontally centered :-) So the problem is to get "list item 1", "list item 2" and "list item 3" to be nicely vertically aligned in the middle of that  red surrounding div, without taking it out of the flow with position absolute og transform translate

Comment: @Dac0d3r I'm trying one more edit. Sorry if that's not what you'e looking for.

Comment: I made a few tweaks to your solution to make it fit my needs, but credit goes to you. Here's what I ended up with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-78pckz?file=style.css

Comment: @Dac0d3r Nice! Never used `align-self: end` before, glad you found a solution... :-)

Comment: Your solution helped a lot. So if you can perhaps adjust it a bit, I'd be happy to approve your answer.

Comment: Made some changes to make it align in the middle. Had to add a 3rd row and a wrapper on the image to make it work. See the example at the end of the post or  stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-78pckz?file=style.css for the changes and please update whenever you have time :D Now the question remains.... can exactly the same behavior be achieved, but in a much nicer and cleaner way? :D